# Is a stock's price different across trading platforms?

Tags: stocks, trading

Let's say I'm looking at a minute stock chart during a trading day. Will E-Trade and TD-Ameritrade for example, show a different price on the minute by minute chart? (or 5-minute chart, etc.)

Comment: The stock price is whatever price the last trade executed at. Depending on how frequently trades occur and when each service updates its chart, they could certainly have different ideas about what the "last" trade was.

Comment: And at what price the last trade occurred is of only partial relevance to what price the _next_ trade will take place at, should you submit an order.

Answer (score 1):

> Will E-Trade and TD-Ameritrade for example, show a different price on the minute by 
>   minute chart?

It is possible they show different charts, but this is not the same question as

> Is a stock's price different across trading platforms?

because a different price may simply be an issue i.e. of time being off on a server. There is a lot of technology that can go wrong.

Price between platforms that follow the same rule SHOULD be identical, but it may differ base on technological issues between platforms (i.e. a data feed is out because a router failed, i.e.).

Answer (score 1):

A one minute chart is a effectively a derivative of price because the provider is collating 60 seconds of data and creating a data point.  It's very reasonable to expect that one platform may do this faster than another.  It's also possible that other technology issues can add a tiny delay to the process (server speed, clock issues, starting/ending point of the minute, etc.).

One would expect that the current trade price/volume info for two platforms should be identical but I can attest to the fact that it's not.  Occasionally, I have seen one of my brokers lag another by a second or two. And if I'm seeing it on the few stocks that I'm intently watching at a given moment, it must be happening an awful lot since there are many, many  thousands of stocks trading.

Answer (score 0):

I thought that maybe it was due to different platforms relying on a small set of different data providers. For example, yesterday the question came up and I checked the first 1-min bar on AMZN and found that TOS/TDA and Barchart were nearly identical, while there was a significant difference between them and TradingView, and Yahoo was way out there with 3176.25 for OHL&C.

```
      TDA   TradingView  Barchart    Yahoo

 O  3176.00   3175.22    3176.01   3176.25

 H  3178.97   3175.22    3178.97   3176.25

 L  3172.00   3173.76    3172.00   3176.25

 C  3176.25   3173.77    3176.25   3176.25
```